# How to get the index of the first time a value is under a threshold (by row)?

Tags: r, performance

I have a lot of values and I want to get the first time where a value is under a threshold in a row.

I tried this code:

```
Threshold<-NULL
t <- 0.75
for(i in 1:dim(Tab)[1]){
  k <- 2
  if(is.na(Tab[i,k])){
    while(((k < dim(Tab)[2])) & (is.na(Tab[i,k]))){
      k <- k+1
    }
  }
  while(((k < dim(Tab)[2]) & (t < Tab[i,k]))){
    k <- k+1
  }
  Threshold[i] <- k
}
```

But it takes a lot of time to run...

For example:

I've got this data frame:

```
Id |   a    |   b   |   c   |   d   |
1  |  0.9   |  0.8  |  0.7  |  0.6  |
2  |  0.55  |  0.4  |  0.8  |  0.2  |
3  |  0.9   |  0.8  |  0.8  |  0.8  |
4  |  0.8   |  0.7  |  1.1  |  0.5  |
5  |   NA   |   NA  |  0.8  |  0.7  |
```

I'm trying to have this result:

```
Threshold= (4 , 2 , NA , 3 , 5)
```

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try with `max.col(df1[-1] < 0.75, "first") * NA^(!rowSums(df1[-1] < 0.75))`

Comment: Can you please check the expected answer.  If the threshold is `<= 0.7`, then `it should be `4, 2, NA, 3, 5`  and the solution would be `(max.col(df1[-1] <= 0.7 & !is.na(df1[-1]), "first") + 1) *NA^(!rowSums(df1[-1] <= 0.7, na.rm = TRUE))#
[1]  4  2 NA  3  5`

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake you're right. I edited it. I will try your answer thanks. For the moment, I have got a memory error, so I will try when I solve this problem!

Comment: No problem.  Let me know if it works and then I can post as a solution to close this

Comment: I tried it and it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the position of the first element in each row which is less than a threshold.  Create a logical index with `rowSums` to account for rows having no elements less than threshold and make it `NA`

```
(max.col(df1[-1] <= 0.7 & !is.na(df1[-1]), "first") + 1) *
        NA^(!rowSums(df1[-1] <= 0.7, na.rm = TRUE))
```